# Diophantine equations in $\Bbb Z$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

$x + 2y + 3z = 4$

$w = x + 2\times y$, then the equation becomes $w + 3z = 4$. $\gcd(1, 3) = 1 | 4$, so this two variable equation is solvable. $w = -2, y = 2$

i can't seem to pass this point

Comment: What exactly confuses you?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142388/linear-diophantine-equations-in-three-variables), or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/514105/how-do-i-solve-a-linear-diophantine-equation-with-three-unknowns). For $ax+by+cz=d$ see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126610/problem-on-linear-diophantine-equation-over-3-variables).

Comment: why does w = -2 n y= 2, n how'd i get the general solution for w and z?

Comment: Please see http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/number-theory/linear-diophantine/linear-diophantine.html

Comment: i've been looking at that example the past hour, i don't get the part when ((3, 5) = 1 | 10, so this two variable equation is solvable. w = 5, y = −1, is a particular solution, so the general solution is
w = 5s + 5, z = −3s −1.

Comment: Are you convinced that if $\gcd(3,5)$ divides $10$ then the equation is solvable?

Comment: yes, i am convinced

Comment: @user241340 So I guess you are not convinced that we have $\textit{all}$ the solutions?

Comment: can you please explain then?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a Diophantine equation $ax+by=c$. If $\gcd(a,b)$ divides $c$, then this equation has solution.$w=-2, y=2$ is one. Then consider the Diophantine equation $x+2y=-2$. $\gcd(1,2)=1$, which divides $-2$ again. So you then solve this equation.